# An object reference is required for the none-static field - nested method creating a bigger method

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a method that uses parameters to create a functionality of a splashScreen, i've done this by using nested methods and then using a method to use the previously made methods as a bigger method. It keeps throwing the same error and i'm not sure why, can anyone help please?

Heres the nested methods:

```
public class methods
{
    public class splash
    {
        Thread t { get; set; }
        public void start()
        {
            Application.Run(new Splash());
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(start));
            t.Start();
        }

        public void action(int time)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(time);
        }

        public void stop()
        {
            t.Abort();
        }

        public void run(int time)
        {
            start();
            action(time);
            stop();
        }
    }
```

Here is where i'm trying to use it:

```
methods.splash.run(5000);
```

This is the error:

> An object reference is required for the none-static field, method or
>   property 'methods.splash.run(int)'

Comment: Search your error message in Google and you will find your answer.

Comment: Note that you don't have any nested *methods* - you have a nested *type*.

Comment: Since you have not made `run` static, you must first make a `new methods.splash()` and then call `run` on that.

Comment: Neither your classes, nor the method are static.  You need an instance of something before you can invoke it.

Comment: oh? I am new to c#, and trying to self teach but not getting on so well thanks for the feed back

Comment: Try finding the difference between the instance member and static member and it would be easier to fit ur requirement.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629(v=vs.71).aspx